# for loop not iterating for second value

Tags: python, html, django

Some explaination about the code:- taking user's multiple input (comma separated) from CmdForm (django form)---> getting it in ipInsert ----> splitting it and stored in ipIns---> then Iteration

but the issue is when i m taking comma separted value, the for loop is not iterating for the second time. displaying the result of input before comma.

In views.py

```
def form_name_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CmdForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            from netmiko import ConnectHandler
            ipInsert = request.POST.get('ip_address', '')
            ipIns = ipInsert.split(',')
            for ipIn in ipIns:
                devices = {
                'device_type':'cisco_ios',
                'ip':ipIn,
                'username':'mee',
                'password':'12345',
                'secret':'12345',
                }
                cmd = request.POST.get('command', '')
                try:
                    netconnect = ConnectHandler(**devices)
                except (AuthenticationException):
                    re = 'Authentication failed.! please try again {}'.format(ipIn)
                    print(re)
                    return render(request,'first_app/forms.html', {'form': form, 'reprinting':re})
                    pass
                except (SSHException):
                    re = 'SSH issue. Are you sure SSH is enabled? {}'.format(ipIn)
                    print(re)
                    return render(request,'first_app/forms.html', {'form': form, 'reprinting':re})
                    pass
                except (NetMikoTimeoutException):
                    re = 'TimeOut to device {}'.format(ipIn)
                    print(re)
                    return render(request,'first_app/forms.html', {'form': form, 'reprinting':re})
                    pass
                except (EOFError):
                    re = 'End of file while attempting device {}'.format(ipIn)
                    print(re)
                    return render(request,'first_app/forms.html', {'form': form, 'reprinting':re})
                    pass
                except Exception as unknown_error:
                    re = 'Some other error {}' .format(unknown_error)
                    print(re)
                    return render(request,'first_app/forms.html', {'form': form, 'reprinting':re})
                    pass

                getIP = netconnect.send_command(ipIn)
                output = netconnect.send_command(cmd)
                now = time.strftime("%Y_%m_%d__%H_%M_%S")
                file = sys.stdout
                file = open("C:/Users/OneDrive/Desktop/frontend/ "+now +".txt", mode='w+')
                file.write("IP address is\n"+ ipIn)
                file.write("\n\nCommand Executed: \n"+ cmd)
                file.write("\n\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
                file.write("\n\nOutput of Executed Command: \n\n\n"+output)
                file.close
                return render(request,'first_app/forms.html', {'form': form, 'output':output, 'getIP':getIP, 'date_time':now})


            #return render(request,'first_app/forms.html', {'form': form, 'output':output, 'getIP':getIP, 'date_time':now})

            #return render(request,'first_app/forms.html', {'form': form, 'output':output, 'getIP':getIP, 'date_time':now})
        else:
            form = CmdForm()
            return render(request,'first_app/forms.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        return render(request,'first_app/forms.html', {})
```

Here's the HTML code:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>FORMS</title>
    </head>
  <body>
    <h1> To run Commands </h1>

<br><br>
<form method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Click Here to run Commands" />
<br>

{% if request.POST %}
<pre>{{ reprinting }}</pre>
{% endif %}

<br>
{% if request.POST %}
{% csrf_token %}
<p>Current date and time is : {{ date_time }} </p>
<p>Command output:</p>
<pre>{{ output }}</pre>
{% endif %}


</form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Within the `for` loop you using `return` statement. That is why `for` loop iteration works only once.

Comment: thx for ur reply. i commented the **return** statement within **for** loop and was able to print the output to the file but on screen the script crashed and didn't showed the result.                  it's showing the error **HttpResponse is none**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first for loop is

```
for ipIn in ipIns:
            [...]
            return render(request,'first_app/forms.html', {'form': form, 'output':output, 'getIP':getIP, 'date_time':now})
```

After the first iteration, the code is returning and stopping the execution. That's why it's stopping after reading the first item.

Edit: What you want to do is to have your for loop and have the return statement AFTER it like so (make sure you get the indentation right):

```
for ipIn in ipIns:
    [...]
return render(request,'first_app/forms.html', {'form': form, 'output':output, 'getIP':getIP, 'date_time':now})
```

Edit 2: Also, you're overwriting instead of appending. Change

```
file = open("C:/Users/karti/OneDrive/Desktop/frontend/ "+now +".txt", mode='w+')
```

to

```
file = open("C:/Users/karti/OneDrive/Desktop/frontend/ "+now +".txt", mode='a+')
```

Comment: thx for ur reply. i commented the return statement within for loop and was able to print the output to the file but on screen the script crashed and didn't showed the result. it's showing the error HttpResponse is none

Comment: The solution isn't to just comment the return statement. Of course, it shows you the response is none. There is no response from your view. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: i m trying to write the output on the file as well as on the screen for each value of iteration both at same time

Comment: Move the return statement after the for loop then.

Comment: can you please specify after which statement should i place the return statement so that i can get the file written and screen output for each iteration at the same time. pls. As in writing the part of code to where it is to be placed. thnku

Comment: No worries, just accept the answer once you fix your problem.

Comment: just found out that ON the screen the result so displayed is of second iteration that is the result of first output is overridden by the result of second output on screen. now how can i display the result of both outputs one after another.? hope u can help.!

Comment: You're overwriting the file instead of appending. Change your w to a in the mode argument.

Comment: after changing from **w** to **a** it is still overriding on web page/ Screen