# last iteration result overriding (on web) the previous outputs

Tags: python, html, django

In reference to the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57094866/for-loop-not-iterating-for-second-value) here are some adjustments i made and further added some functionalities.

In [Previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57094866/for-loop-not-iterating-for-second-value) the loop was iterating for **multiple IPs** and **single command** but now i want tje loop to iterate for **multiple IPs and multiple commands** & for that i added one more **for** loop.

As in code everything is fine while writing the file but In HttpResponse the result of last **output** is overriding the previous **outputs**

views.py

```py
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from first_app.forms import CmdForm
    from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
    import netmiko
    from netmiko import ConnectHandler
    from netmiko.ssh_exception import NetMikoTimeoutException
    from paramiko.ssh_exception import SSHException
    from netmiko.ssh_exception import AuthenticationException
    import datetime, time, sys
    from django.urls import reverse
    # Create your views here.

    def form_name_view(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = CmdForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                from netmiko import ConnectHandler
                ipInsert = request.POST.get('ip_address', '')   #taking multiple IPS
                ipIns = ipInsert.split(',')                     #splitting IPs CSVs

                cmd = request.POST.get('command', '')       #tking multiple Commands
                cmdlist = cmd.split(',')                    #splitting commands

                for ipIn in ipIns:                          #for eqch in IP in IP list
                    for cmdSingle in cmdlist:               #for eah command in Command list
                        devices = {
                        'device_type':'cisco_ios',
                        'ip':ipIn,
                        'username':'mee',
                        'password':'12345',
                        'secret':'12345',
                        }

                        try:
                            netconnect = ConnectHandler(**devices)      
                        except (AuthenticationException):
                            re = 'Authentication failed.! please try again {}'.format(ipIn)
                            print(re)
                            return render(request,'first_app/forms.html', {'form': form, 'reprinting':re})
                            pass
                        except (SSHException):
                            re = 'SSH issue. Are you sure SSH is enabled? {}'.format(ipIn)
                            print(re)
                            return render(request,'first_app/forms.html', {'form': form, 'reprinting':re})
                            pass
                        except (NetMikoTimeoutException):
                            re = 'TimeOut to device {}'.format(ipIn)
                            print(re)
                            return render(request,'first_app/forms.html', {'form': form, 'reprinting':re})
                            pass
                        except (EOFError):
                            re = 'End of file while attempting device {}'.format(ipIn)
                            print(re)
                            return render(request,'first_app/forms.html', {'form': form, 'reprinting':re})
                            pass
                        except Exception as unknown_error:
                            re = 'Some other error {}' .format(unknown_error)
                            print(re)
                            return render(request,'first_app/forms.html', {'form': form, 'reprinting':re})
                            pass

                        output = netconnect.send_command(cmdSingle)         #sending command to router
                        now = time.strftime("%Y_%m_%d__%H_%M_%S")           #print command on web
                        file = sys.stdout                                   #standard output in txt file
                        file = open("C:/Users/OneDrive/Desktop/frontend/ "+now+"__"+ipIn +".txt", mode='a+')  #open and append file
                        file.write("IP address is\n"+ ipIn)                        # write IP address to file
                        file.write("\n\nCommand Executed: \n"+ cmdSingle)           #write command to file
                        file.write("\n\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
                        file.write("\n\nOutput of Executed Command: \n\n\n"+output)         #writing output to file
                        file.close

                return render(request,'first_app/forms.html', {'form': form, 'output':output, 'getIP':ipIn,     
                                                                        'date_time':now, 'ipList':ipIns,
                                                                        'cmdlist':cmdlist,'cmdSingle':cmdSingle})       #http response on web
            else:
                form = CmdForm()
                return render(request,'first_app/forms.html', {'form': form})
        else:
            return render(request,'first_app/forms.html', {})
```

forms.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>FORMS</title>
    <style>
    table, th, td {
      style=width:100%;
      max-height:100px;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    #lengthy{

      max-height:50px;
      overflow-y: scroll;
            height:50px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
  <body>
    <h1> Run Commands </h1>

<form method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
{% for field in form %}
   <div class="fieldWrapper">
       {{ field.errors }} <br>
       {{ field.label_tag }} <br/>
       {{ field }}
   </div>
   {% endfor %}
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Click Here to run Commands" />
<br>

{% if request.POST %}
<pre>{{ reprinting }}</pre>
{% endif %}

<br>
{% if request.POST %}
{% csrf_token %}

  <table>

    <tr>
      <th>Current date and time</th>
      <th>IP address </th>
      <th>Command Executed </th>
      <th>Output</th>
    </tr>


  {% for getIP in ipList %}
    {% for cmdSingle in cmdlist %}
      <tr>
        <td style="width:20%"> {{ date_time }} </td>
        <td style="width:15%"><pre> {{ getIP }} </pre></td>
        <td style="width:20%"><pre> {{ cmdSingle }} </pre></td>
        <td id="lengthy" style="width:90%"><pre>{{ output }}</pre></td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}

  </table>


{% endif %}


</form>
  </body>
</html>
```

thx for the help.!

Comment: @pranjal0819 what r u trying to do ?

Comment: where you find **last output is overriding the previous outputs**. In output file or HTML page

Comment: when i locally run the django server the output of last iteration is overidding the output of previous iterations on web (local browser),**IN file everything is working fine as expected**

Comment: the standard rule: if you have more then one element then keep them on list.

Comment: append every output to file or database and later  get all outputs from file/database and send to HTML.

Comment: for that i have to open a file and in doing this the code will take more time to execute and if suppose the user wants to get the file written and display ouput at the same time and/or the user wants output to be displayed first (on HTML page) and use the file written for later purposes. then ur idea might not work here.!

Comment: Writing file is the secondary thing but the primary requirement is to display the result on HTML page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should build list of lists and show the output in template. Like this:

```
 def form_name_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CmdForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # rest of the code
            output_list = list()
            for ipIn in ipIns:                        
                for cmdSingle in cmdlist: 
                    # try catch block
                    output = netconnect.send_command(cmdSingle)
                    output_list.append([ipIn, cmdSingle, output])  # appending ip, cmd and output as a list to output list
                    # rest of the code

            return render(request,'first_app/forms.html', {'form': form, 'output_list':output_list, 'date_time':now})
```

Then render it in template:

```
{% for getIP, cmdSingle, output in output_list %}
  <tr>
    <td style="width:20%"> {{ date_time }} </td>
    <td style="width:15%"><pre> {{ getIP }} </pre></td>
    <td style="width:20%"><pre> {{ cmdSingle }} </pre></td>
    <td id="lengthy" style="width:90%"><pre>{{ output }}</pre></td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```